# How to Update or Re-Install the newest version of ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I have an android based phone and I need ADB for installing new versions. However, until today ADB was working perfectly but today I got an error, it says "you need 1.0.32 or newer version." Yes, error is clear enough. Problem is, how ?

For the records, I've tried to remove ADB. 
With :

```
sudo apt-get remove android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Then I re-installed it with :

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Before this commands my ADB version was 1.0.31, still it is 1.0.31. But here ( http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) As far as I see, there is new version, 1.0.35. But with terminal All I'm getting is 1.0.31. 
I've downloaded 1.0.35 zip but I don't know what to do with it.

How Can I uprade my ADB?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you think, you have latest SDK but the adb tool is older one,

Use,

```
# adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
# wget -O - https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+archive/cd048d18e0b81338c1a04b9749a00444597df394/platform_tools/android/bin/linux.tar.gz | tar -zxvf - adb
# sudo mv adb /usr/bin/adb
# sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
# adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

Refernce http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/328-ubuntu-trusty-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb

Comment: is this a trusted source?

Comment: This is Google builds repo. Nothing is safer than that.

Comment: nice and neat answer. In some OS like Ubuntu 14.04, it is located at `usr/local/bin/adb`.

Comment: using your commands I have update from Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
to Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
thank you man , I couldn't do it without your help :)

Answer (score 15):

You can download the latest SDK including adb [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other).  When you extract this archive, there is a readme which explains how to install the SDK.  I list it here for your reference.

```
Welcome to the Android SDK!

The Android SDK archive initially contains only the basic SDK tools. It does
not contain an Android platform or any third-party libraries. In fact, it
doesn't even have all the tools you need to develop an application.

In order to start developing applications, you must install the Platform-tools
and at least one version of the Android platform, using the SDK Manager.

Platform-tools contains build tools that are periodically updated to support new
features in the Android platform (which is why they are separate from basic
SDK tools), including adb, dexdump, and others.

To install Platform-tools, Android platforms and other add-ons, you must
have an Internet connection, so if you plan to use the SDK while
offline, please make sure to download the necessary components while online.

To start the SDK Manager, please execute the program "android".

From the command-line you can also directly trigger an update by
executing:
  tools/android update sdk --no-ui

Tip: use --help to see the various command-line options.


For more information, please consult the Android web site at
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/
```

Once installed (you will have to install Java if you don't have it already), you can navigate to android-sdk-linux/platform-tools and execute adb from there by typing

```
./adb [options]
```

I freely admit this may not be the most elegant solution but it works for me.  ISTR that on a different Ubuntu machine I managed a minimal install with just platform-tools sans Java, but I cannot find my notes on that.

Comment: Yes, I saw that txt but the commands was like elvish language so I found myself on askubuntu :)

Comment: Extract the archive, then go into the tools folder and doubleclick the "android" file.   Click on Run in Terminal.

Comment: there is no tools folder. 
I've downloadede "All Android Studio Packages" but there is no Tools folder in it.
The list of folders in zip :
bin
grandle
lib
license
plugins

Comment: Go to the link I provided and download android-sdk_r24.1.2-linux.tgz

Comment: well, It works but I do not need that app, All I need is using "adb sideload <filename>" command but my ADB is 'still' 1.0.31 I need to update my ADB 1.0.32 or newer.

Comment: When I installed it using this process I got 1.0.32  make sure you are in the platform-tools directory and type ./adb version not just adb version

Comment: Finally my firend. I got into new platform-folder and as you said I typed ./adb not adb. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

There are great answers already posted here but for an extremely simple method, just grab the latest platform tools without all the extra bloat and combine with a bash alias for convenience.

This will create a new directory 'Android' at the root of your home directory. Change the paths below (and in my example bash aliases) if you prefer a different location.

```
mkdir ~/Android && cd ~/Android
```

Next download and extract the platform tools from Google:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip && unzip platform-tools-latest-linux.zip
```

Now the latest `adb`, `fastboot`, and other tools are available to run directly from the newly extracted 'platform-tools' directory. Use bash aliases to make them easier to use (after uninstalling the obsolete distribution packages to avoid conflicts). This example command will alias the `adb` command, making it immediately available for use:

```
echo "alias adb='~/Android/platform-tools/adb'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases
```

And optionally for `fastboot` too:

```
echo "alias fastboot='~/Android/platform-tools/fastboot'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Updating is as simple as `cd`'ing to the Android directory and repeating the download and extract step again. Use `adb version` to check your currently installed version.

Comment: Please don't forget we could not have unzip, you could mention to install it before all operations.

Comment: @Tom Brossman `adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (41)`. What to do?

Comment: Best answer. Concise, fast. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Improving on Organic Marble's answer, to only install the latest tools (not the whole sdk), use the platform-tool filter as below:

```
tools/android update sdk -t platform-tool --no-ui
```

Comment: Thanks! I had figured that out but lost my notes.

Answer (score 2):

I will add some stuff I learned earlier today.

I had two versions of `adb` installed at the same time due to a fascinating series of steps, Ubuntu 18.04; somehow an earlier version of the Android SDK created a symlink in `/usr/bin/adb`, so firing up React Native packager would pull from a conflicting adb and cause fairly difficult to interpret symptoms. I think it was because I installed remove+reinstalled Android Studio.

`/home/<USER>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` is the default location your adb executable will be found in.

You can check its version by:

```
$ ./adb version
```

Here are the path variables you might find:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Then you can make sure your system is using it with:

```
sudo ln -s /home/<USER>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
```

That would allow you to use from a custom installation directory as well; replace `/home/<USER>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb` with the path to your executable.