# Google Pixel not picked up by "adb devices"

Tags: 14.04, android, adb

I've tried everything I can find anywhere.

From lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 18d1:4ee6 Google Inc.
```

From dmsg:

```
[ 3609.392038] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 3609.411721] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee6
[ 3609.411729] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3609.411734] usb 2-1: Product: Pixel
[ 3609.411738] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Google
[ 3609.411742] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: FAXXXXXXXXXX
```

Result of adb devices:

```
List of devices attached
```

with a blank line following

I've tried everything from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632651/adb-devices-command-wont-detect-my-4-4-android-phone) question/answer, and none of it worked.

What's odd is that it gets picked up and works from android studio, but not through terminal.

Comment: @LehiC I've tried MTP and PTP, and pretty much all usb modes

Comment: I had a similar issue. Plus eclipse ADT was not recognizing it as well. Followed this: http://turlucode.com/linux-android-adb-fix-permissions/ and got this working. MTP/PTP was not related in my case: my phone was even in USB charging mode. Only Debugging mode was on ofc. This was tested also with Android O. Hope it will help you as well!

Answer (score 8):

I was also getting errors trying to connect my Pixel device:

`AA69M0123456   no permissions (verify udev rules); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]`

Even after setting up udev rules, unplugging/replugging, adb kill-server/startserver, re-enable developer options on the phone, etc... it still wouldn't connect.

It was because the phone USB mode was set to `Charge this device`. Switching it to `Transfer files` (via the notification menu) finally made it work.

Comment: Found it: Developer Options, Select USB Configuration. I set it to MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) Mode, and now the phone shows up. It was also in Charging mode for me

Comment: Also, "USB debugging" - for me, I enabled it and it started showing up on the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I'll re-word and be more specific, as I believe my previous answer to this may have been misconstrued.

I'm under the assumption that you are attempting to access the phone's internal storage and/or the SD card inserted.

That being the case, if the phone is running Android OS (it's Google, it should be), then you should receive a notification as to the mode the phone is in, with regard to the USB connection.

Typically, simply pulling down the notifications section would allow you to "tap and toggle". Other than that, you can go into the settings section of the phone to see if there is an option to toggle it to something resembling the wording "Share Files".

Aside from that, you may need to dive into the documentation that should have been provided with the phone.

Since it seems to support Mac (which is also UNIX based) it, hypothetically, should be usable with Linux. Aside from that, you may need to contact Google directly for more explicit instructions for getting the phone to interact with Ubuntu.

https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2840804?hl=en

Comment: `adb` is not typically used "to access the phone's internal storage and/or the SD card inserted".  Rather, it "is a versatile command line tool that lets you communicate with an emulator instance or connected Android device. "

Comment: Since OP mentions Android Studio I don't think that access to the internal storage is going to be enough. During software development one needs to execute additional commands on the phone.

Comment: @DavidFoerster this is correct. There are several "how-tos" that I've read that all start with "make sure your device is visible via adb devices"

Comment: You have the full capacity to edit your questions here, instead of reposting you can just edit an answer to make it more informative, etc. next time

Answer (score 1):

When faced with the same issue as the OP I came across this post. I wanted to come back and contribute what worked for me.

I discovered the version of ADB that ships with Ubuntu is 1.0.31 which only works up to Android 5. You need the newest adb version 1.0.32 which supports Android v7.1 which is what ships with the Pixel. That question was answered here: [How to Update or Re-Install the newest version of ADB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602129/how-to-update-or-re-install-the-newest-version-of-adb/629243#629243)

I also discovered that there's a bug with USB 3 on some machines, plugging in a cheap USB 2 hub (or an old adaptor) was the final ticket to getting `adb devices` to detect my Pixel. (It sounded weird to me too, but it worked).

I'm not sure if adding a udev rule helped or not, but I did also did try that earlier in the process. Maybe if someone else comes along they'll be able to clarify that step.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a different USB cable worked for me on a pixel 5 using adb and droidcam.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem with getting ADB to recognize a Google Pixel 6 Pro phone with Android 12.1.0 was attempting to use a Pixel Stand (2nd Gen) cable instead of the cable that came with the phone (since I didn't want to walk out to my car to get the latter).

If USB debugging is already enabled, there should be a "USB debugging connected" notification on the phone when the cable is connected to both the phone and computer, but that notification didn't appear at all when the Pixel Stand cable was used. Otherwise, the `adb devices` command will return nothing.

If the device is recognized, but listed as "unauthorized", USB debugging needs to be disabled and re-enabled with the cable connected to trigger an access permission prompt on the phone.